# React Native navigate not updating props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have one page with a list of "tenants". When I select one tenant if shows the data for this specific tenant. It is working. However, when I navigate back to the tenant list and select another tenant, it does not update the this.props with the new tenant data.

My Tenant Details Page

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tenantData: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getTenantID();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // needs to be a unique value
      if (prevProps.tenantData.Email !== this.props.tenantData.Email) {
         this.getTenantID();
       }
  }

  getTenantID = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
    await this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID); // Wait for action to complete
    this.setState({
      tenantData: this.props.tenantData
    });
  };
```

My action:

```
export const getTenantByID = (tID) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('http://myirent.com/rent/components/iRentApp.cfc', {
      params: {
        method: 'getTenantByTenant',
        tenantID: tID
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      const tenant = response.data.DATA[0];
        console.log(tenant);
      const getTenant = {
        FirstName: tenant[1],
        LastName: tenant[2],
        Email: tenant[5],
        Phone: tenant[6],
        Unit: tenant[11],
        MiddleName: tenant[3],
        RentalAmount: tenant[4],
        MoveInDate: getFormattedDate(tenant[7]),
        MoveOutDate: getFormattedDate(tenant[8]),
        LeaseStartDate: getFormattedDate(tenant[9]),
        LeaseEndDate: getFormattedDate(tenant[10])
      };
      dispatch({
        type: GET_TENANT_DATA,
        payload: getTenant
      });
    });
  };
};
```

The tenantID is being updated and the action response data too. It looks like that the page is loading before updating the this.props.tenantData

Comment: It looks like you're mixing navigation params and props parameters.  If you're using react navigation to navigate to the details screen, only the `this.props.navigation` value is valid - any other parameters must be passed as parameters to the `navigate` call.

Answer (score 1):

The `componentDidUpdate()` is called immediately after the update. This method is not called in the first rendering.

[image: lifecycle]

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      // typical use cases (don't forget the props comparison)
      if (prevProps.navigation !== this.props.navigation) {
         const data = this.props.navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0')
         this.getTenantID(data);
       }
  }

  getTenantID = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const tenantID = navigation.getParam('tenantID', '0');
   const tenantdata = await this.props.getTenantByID(tenantID); // Wait for action to complete
    this.setState({
      tenantData: tenantdata,
      updateid : tenantID
    });
  };
```

Comment: Why did you create the updatedid state variable? It still not working

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 I was mistaked. I modified the answer.

Comment: @myTest532myTest532 If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' mark and arrow for my answer?